# tkinter breaks when spawned as subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, macos, operating-system

I am trying to create a 'reminder' GUI app in python.

When I implement the Tkinter to open a popup in the main module everything works fine. But, when I try to create a window in a child process forked from the main process, **I get a MacOS error message and window that says 'python quit unexpectedly'**, which looks like the process was trying to access kernel space?

How do I get around this?

Here is the **source code** -

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkmacosx import Button
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from json import load as loadjson
import time
import atexit
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import signal

def kill_children(da_q: Queue) -> None:
    while da_q.empty() == False:
        proc_id_to_kill = da_q.get()
        os.kill(proc_id_to_kill,signal.SIGTERM)


def init_logging(requested_log_level: str = logging.DEBUG) -> logging.getLogger:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(requested_log_level)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(requested_log_level)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - [%(name)s/function_name=%(funcName)s/pid=%(process)d/pname=%(processName)s] - %(levelname)s - %(message)s ")
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    ch2 = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('reminders.log')
    ch2.setLevel(requested_log_level)
    ch2.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch2)
    return logger


def pop_up_window(reminder_obj: dict) -> None:
    logger.info("started pop_up_window process")
    logger.debug("threshold="+str(int(reminder_obj["reminder_frequency_in_minutes"])*60))
    start_time = time.time()
    logger.debug(f"start time={start_time}")
    time.sleep(10)
    cur_time = time.time()
    logger.debug(f"cur_time={cur_time}")
    diff = cur_time - start_time
    logger.debug(f"diff={diff}")
    while diff < (int(reminder_obj["reminder_frequency_in_minutes"])*60):
        time.sleep(10)
        cur_time = time.time()
        logger.debug(f"cur_time={cur_time}")
        diff = cur_time - start_time
        logger.debug(f"diff={diff}")
    if diff >= (int(reminder_obj["reminder_frequency_in_minutes"])*60):
        logger.info("reminder time reached. generate window.")
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . Center')
        window.rowconfigure(0, minsize=50, weight=1)
        window.columnconfigure([0, 1, 2], minsize=50, weight=1)
        window.title("Reminder: ")
        hide_btn = Button(master=window,text="hide",command=hide_window, fg="Black")
        label = tk.Label(text="drink water")
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        hide_btn.grid(row=1,column=1)
        window.mainloop()
    
    
    def hide_window() -> None:
        logger.debug(f"destroy window {__name__}")
        exit(0)


def proc_handler(reminder_obj: list,da_q: Queue) -> None:
    logger.debug("started handler for reminder=")
    logger.debug(reminder_obj)
    logger.debug("starting popup window subprocess forever, till parent kills it...")
    while True:
        p = Process(target=pop_up_window, args=(reminder_obj,))
        p.start()
        logger.debug("started. pid="+str(p.pid))
        q.put(p.pid)
        p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = init_logging()
    logger.debug("started.")
    atexit.register(kill_children)
    logger.debug("registered kill-children on exit")
    q = Queue()
    logger.debug("created process-safe queue")
    with open("reminders.json") as rmf:
        reminders = loadjson(rmf)
    logger.info("loaded reminders config file successfully.")
    reminder_handler_processes = []
    for reminder in reminders:
        logger.info("initing processes..")
        reminder_handler = Process(target=proc_handler,args=(reminder,q,))
        reminder_handler_processes.append(reminder_handler)
    logger.debug("processes=")
    logger.debug(repr(reminder_handler_processes))
    logger.info("starting handlers...")
    for handler_proc in reminder_handler_processes:
        handler_proc.start()
        logger.debug("started ... pid="+str(handler_proc.pid))
        q.put(handler_proc.pid)
```

The supplementary files

**reminders.json**

```
[
    {
        "reminder_name":"get_up_and_walk",
        "reminder_message":"Get up and walk",
        "reminder_frequency_in_minutes":1
    },
    {
        "reminder_name":"drink_water",
        "reminder_message":"Drink Some Water",
        "reminder_frequency_in_minutes":2
    }
]
```

**requirements.txt** incase you want to create a venv and test it yourself.

```
astroid==2.4.2
colour==0.1.5
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==2.5.3
six==1.15.0
tk==0.1.0
tkmacosx==0.1.4
toml==0.10.1
typed-ast==1.4.1
wrapt==1.12.1
```

Comment: Can you share the complete trackback error? Or do you just get the `'python quit unexpectedly'` error alone?

Comment: I don't get a python stacktrace, I get a macos system error message. Something like [this](https://ctxt.io/2/AADA00KpEA)

Comment: @Saad So, I also got this error when I tried to create the window in the forked process. `The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().`

Comment: try using some different python version

Comment: It seems that this is a lot tricker than I first thought it would be. It seems that [MacOS does not allow creation and termination of GUI components like `NSWindow` outside of the main thread (rightfully so)](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/crash-on-macos-10-14-mojave-with-sdl-showmessagebox/25100). [Here is the stacktrace](https://ctxt.io/2/AADA74laFA). I'll respond back with a solution when I find a workaround.